# PHP - Regular Expression Stops at "&nbsp;"

Tags: regex

I am working with regular expressions to transform HTML into BBCODE. But, with code coming from farmer WYSIWYG editors (TinyMce) I am getting issues. It is a very curious case:

There are some typical blank pharagraphs, `<p>&nbsp;</p>`, but I cannot match them in any way. No one of the folllowing regexp's are working:

```
str_replace("<p>&nbsp;</p>",........)
str_replace("<p> </p>".........)
preg_replace("#<p>.?</p>#"....)
```

**This DOES work, but what if the "spaces" are in other places, how could I match them?**:

```
preg_replace("#<p>.{1,6}</p>#"....)
```

How can I get it to match all the `&nbsp;` even if they aren't written (in the BD, where the original string is stored, the `&nbsp;` are not written, there are just `<p> </p>` blocks) It is quite strange...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to read **[Unicode Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)** and **[Wikipedia: Unicode Whitespace character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode)**.

*Script:*

```
$string = '123<p>  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  </p>abc';
$pattern = '/<p>(&nbsp;|[\s\p{Z}\p{C}\x85\xA0\x{0085}\x{00A0}\x{FFFD}]+)*<\/p>/iu'; 
$replacement = ''; 
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

*Output:*

```
123abc
```

---

Note: To match any single unicode grapheme use pattern `\P{M}\p{M}*+`

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an interactive debug session.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue (**PHP process stop**) when used this regular expression:

`([\r\n\t ]|\xC2\xA0|&nbsp;)+`

to match spaces (*my purpose: replace any kind of spaces with single `' '`*). My tested string is rich of HTML tags.

This is my solution:

`$text = str_replace( array( '\xC2\xA0', '&nbsp;' ), ' ', $text );
$text = preg_replace( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", ' ', $text );`

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

ptguys solution almost worked for me, but the char-codes have to be inside double qoutes in order to be parsed by PHP:

```
$text = str_replace( array( "\xC2\xA0", '&nbsp;' ), ' ', $text );
$text = preg_replace( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", ' ', $text );
```